# What's wrong with my program?

Tags: c

I have written a program which could sort 5 strings you inputed from small to big. However, it can't work. I have worked at it for almost an hour, but I couldn't find out the problem. Here is the code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    main() {
    char *sz[5], *temp;
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        gets(sz[i]);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for(j = i+1; j < 5; j++) {
            if(strcmp(sz[i], sz[j]) > 0) {
                temp = sz[i];
                sz[i] = sz[j];
                sz[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        puts(sz[i]);
        puts("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which inputs trigger the problem? What outputs do you get when given those inputs? Have you tried all same length, in increasing size, and in decreasing size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First huge problem is that you are using a routine that should never have existed, and using it improperly:

```
char *sz[5], *temp;
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    gets(sz[i]);
```

You did not allocate any storage for `gets()` to store into, so it is simply scribbling on unrelated memory. (This often leads to [security problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).)

You should pay special attention to the `BUGS` section in your manpages:

```
BUGS
   Never use gets().  Because it is impossible to tell without
   knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will
   read, and because gets() will continue to store characters
   past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use.
   It has been used to break computer security.  Use fgets()
   instead.
```

Unlearn `gets(3)`, now, and be a happier programmer.

Use `malloc()` to allocate some memory for those character arrays.

[Ignacio hit another problem squarely on the head](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10992299/377270) -- you're printing before your sort is finished. Add another loop to print, after the sorting. (Better yet, put the input, sort, and output into three separate functions. Perhaps you're not there yet, but it would be well worth doing this sooner rather than later, as it makes testing your programs significantly easier to have printing functions you can use for debugging.)

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> char *sz[5], *temp;
> int i, j;
> for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
>     gets(sz[i]); /* Tries to write data to random location. */
>     fflush(stdin);
> }
> ```

At least 3 problems:

- You're writing to uninitialized pointers. You need to initialize `sz[i]` before using it (perhaps using `malloc`)
- `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, drop it
- `gets` is unsafe and was removed from the standard, drop it as well and use `fgets` instead

Answer (score 2):

You are passing uninitialized pointers to `gets`, storing the data in random locations. This is undefined behavior. You should allocate memory for your data, and use `fgets` with limits to read strings.

```
char *sz[5], *temp;
int i, j;
char buf[100];
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    fgets (buf , 100 , stdin);
    sz[i] = strdup(buf);
}
... sort your strings...
// Free the strings before exiting the program
for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) free(sz[i]);
```